# How do I properly encrypt a document with GPG2 on Mac?

Tags: gnupg

Here is what I have done roughly, starting from scratch:

```
$ brew install gnupg
$ cat >foo <<EOF
   Key-Type: RSA
   Key-Length: 4096
   Subkey-Type: RSA
   Subkey-Length: 4096
   Name-Real: My Name
   Name-Comment: ...
   Name-Email: ...
   Expire-Date: ...
   Passphrase: 
EOF
$ gpg --batch --full-generate-key foo
gpg: key ... marked as ultimately trusted
gpg: revocation certificate stored as '/Users/username/.gnupg/openpgp-revocs.d/....rev'
$ gpg --list-keys
pub   rsa2048 2013-11-23 [SC]
      ...key1...
uid           [ultimate] My Name <email@email.com>
sub   rsa2048 2019-10-26 [E]

pub   rsa4096 2019-10-26 [SC]
....
$ gpg --output me.asc --armor --export ...key1...
$ gpg --import me.asc
gpg: key ...: no valid user IDs
gpg: this may be caused by a missing self-signature
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:           w/o user IDs: 1
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.17
```

What I would like to finish doing is finally encrypt a document.

```
$ gpg --encrypt file.png --recipient "???"
```

Not quite there yet. Wondering why I am getting this error:

```
gpg: key ...: no valid user IDs
gpg: this may be caused by a missing self-signature
```

What steps am I missing? What did I do wrong or do I need to do?

Do I want a "self signature", or do I want to somehow sign this with some trusted party (I'm vaguely familiar with self-signed SSH certificates, which is what I'm drawing the parallel with).

Comment: It seems that there is no valid user id on that key you generated, but as it was redacted, it is hard to see where the issue may be.